# Defining a derivative as a function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to define the following function

```
Df[k_, t_, x_, M_] = 1/Factorial[k] D[Exp[-(4 M x t)/(1 - t)], {t, k}]
```

I want to differentiate that exponential with respect to t k times but I also want to attribute a value to t after the derivation. But when I call this function with the arguments

```
Df[1,0,1,1]
```

for example I get a message saying that zero is not a valid variable. I think it is making t=0 before the derivation. Is there anyway around this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Define it like this: `Df[k_, t_, x_, M_] := 
 1/Factorial[k] D[Exp[-(4 M x t0)/(1 - t0)], {t0, k}] /. t0 -> t`. (This is a dupe, but I have not time to search.)

Comment: Try `SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-(4 M x \[FormalT])/(1 - \[FormalT])], {\[FormalT], t, k}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
Df[k_, t_, x_,  M_] := (1/Factorial[k] D[Exp[-(4 M x tt)/(1 - tt)], {tt, k}]) /.  tt -> t
```

Test it:

```
In=  Df[1, 0, 1, 1]
Out= (* -4 *)
```

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gabu If it suits you, please accept by clicking the "tick" below the vote count. You can also add an upvote if you think it deserves it.